# docker run pass arguments to entrypoint

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I am able to pass the environment variables using the `-e` option.
But i am not sure how to pass command line arguments to the jar in entrypoint using the docker run command.

Dockerfile

```
FROM openjdk
ADD . /dir
WORKDIR /dir
COPY ./test-1.0.1.jar /dir/test-1.0.1.jar
ENTRYPOINT java -jar /dir/test-1.0.1.jar
```

test.sh

```
#! /bin/bash -l

export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=$(aws configure get aws_access_key_id)
export AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=$(aws configure get aws_secret_access_key)

$value=7

docker run -e AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=$AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID -e AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=$AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY  -i -t testjava  $value
```

Answer (score 124, accepted):

Use `ENTRYPOINT` in its exec form

```
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "/dir/test-1.0.1.jar"]
```

then when you run `docker run -it testjava $value`, `$value` will be "appended" after your entrypoint, just like `java -jar /dir/test-1.0.1.jar $value`

Comment: ...and will override CMD from dockerfile (if it present)

Comment: It does not work for me with the single quotes, `docker run myimage --build` complains about _--build: [npx,: not found_ (my dockerfile: `ENTRYPOINT ['npx', 'mycommand']`). Changing them to double quotes will work, i.e. `ENTRYPOINT ["npx", "mycommand"]`

Comment: You have to use double quotes because it is actually using the JSON array syntax.

Answer (score 75):

You should unleash the power of combination of `ENTRYPOINT` and `CMD`.

Put the beginning part of your command line, which is not expected to change, into `ENTRYPOINT` and the tail, which should be configurable, into `CMD`. Then you can simple append necessary arguments to your `docker run` command.
Like this:

Dockerfile

```
FROM openjdk
ADD . /dir
WORKDIR /dir
COPY ./test-1.0.1.jar /dir/test-1.0.1.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar"]
CMD ["/dir/test-1.0.1.jar"]
```

Sh

```
# this will run default jar - /dir/test-1.0.1.jar
docker run testjava

# this will run overriden jar
docker run testjava /dir/blahblah.jar
```

[This article](http://web.archive.org/web/20180925095640/https://medium.freecodecamp.org/docker-entrypoint-cmd-dockerfile-best-practices-abc591c30e21) gives a good explanation.

Comment: Nice! but what if I want to pass more than one command line arguments?

Comment: The contents at linked URL were replaced with something different, apparently.

Comment: @xpt from `java --help` : `Arguments following [...] -jar <jarfile> [...] are passed as the arguments to main class`. So running `docker run testjava /dir/blahblah.jar -myarg1 -myarg2withvalue 123`. See also : `docker run --help`